# external table is not in the expected format issue

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

i have the issue: "external table is not in the expected format" I have tried various fixes. Changing from Jet to Ace, Installing Access Database Engine as a means to facilitate Ace, I have changed the Extended Properties from 8.0 to 12.0 and vice-versa.  Is there any other fix anyone can suggest?

```
private void button7_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = " \"C:\\Users\\jdavis\\Downloads\\Pharmacies\\CrossReferencing v3\\CrossReferencing\\bin\\Debug\\cross_check.xls\" ";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties= Excel 12.0;");
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand( "SELECT *FROM [cross_check]",con);
        DataSet cross = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(cross);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = cross.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you import from the file in Access?  (I.e. is the problem definitely not with the file itself?)

Comment: Am just looking through my work computer. Could access not being installed be the problem?

Comment: Maybe. But I'd expect that if that were the problem it would be because of some driver Access installs and uses, that you don't currently have.  Do you definitely have the Ace driver installed?

Comment: Yes I installed them through the MS Access Database Engine.exe file

Comment: Another problem could be that the `bin` directory is usually read-only.  Even though you're executing a query, it may have the effect of trying to open the file for read-write access.  Can you try putting the file somewhere else, or changing your `bin` directory to not be read-only?

Comment: Did that but strangely enough it is telling me it couldn't find the excel file with that name..which is weird because the file is right there. I just copied the path exactly as is

Comment: What is it that's telling you it can't find the Excel file?  Your program?  Windows?

Comment: The program. Exception

Comment: You've still got the file in the `bin` directory?  Try moving it out to My Documents or something and see if that helps.

Comment: Yeah I followed your advice before andI moved it to my downloads folder and that is the error